# Why isnt my color palette showing?

Tags: css

Trying to make myself a color palette and for the life of me I cannot work out why my background colors are not showing? Any suggestions? The `color:red;` of `.one` does work.

```
<style>
    .pallette{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        margin-bottom:2em;
    }

    .one{
        background:#FCFFF5;
    }

    .two{
        background:#FCFFF5;

    }

    .three{
        background:#FCFFF5;

    }

    .four{
        background:#FCFFF5;

    }

    .five{
        background:#FCFFF5;

    }
</style>

<div class="pallette one">#FCFFF5</div>
<div class="pallette two">#D1DBBD</div>
<div class="pallette three">#91AA9D</div>
<div class="pallette four">#3E606F</div>
<div class="pallette five">#193441</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've set all your CSS declarations to have identical values, not those shown in your HTML.